# Не могу получить значение переменной из другого метода

Tags: java, android-studio

Я объявляю в активности переменную: `private String getDataFromDB = "";`

Затем я присваиваю ей значение по ключу из БД.

```
private void signalAnswerFirebase() {
        //получаем значения из базы данных
        DocumentReference contactListen = db.collection("collection").document("document");
        contactListen.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot doc, FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                if (doc != null && doc.exists()) {
                    getDataFromBD = doc.getString("User"); 
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Но далее этого метода переменная не видна.

Comment: Где объявлена переменная?

Comment: на уровне класса

Comment: Что значит не видна? Что выдает ошибку компиляции?

Comment: Пройдя дебагером я увидел, что значение переменной null. Но вот если создать TextView и поместить его прямо в метод, то можно заметить, что значение в на экран выводится нормально. Выходит, что метод асинхронный.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте public если в этом есть необходимость, либо правильнее public getter и вызывайте его вне скоупа объекта

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает. Метод асинхронный. Есть варианты получить значения?